ошибка в питоне, sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: users
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot=telebot.TeleBot('токен')
name=''
info=''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуй, это бот -.\nЕсли нужна помощь пропиши /help')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def pomosh(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Список доступных команд:')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg'])
def regist(message):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('polzovateli.sql')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50))''')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши свое имя. Его будут видеть все пользователя')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)

def user_name(message):
    global name
    name=message.text.strip()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('polzovateli.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("{name}")')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    markup=telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список пользователей', callback_data='users'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы зарегистрированы', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    global info
    conn = sqlite3.connect('polzovateli.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    users=cur.fetchall()
    for i in users:
        info+=f'\nИмя:{i[1]}'
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, info)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Есть бот который должен создавать таблицу с именем пользователя, а при нажатии на кнопку выводить список пользователей. Но почему то он не находит таблицу хотя она создается.
Буду признателен если сможете помочь

А она точно создаётся? Сделайте создание таблицы сразу при запуске бота (вне всех функций). Сейчас только после команды "reg" у вас таблица создаётся. Вы её отдавали?

Да, после того как команду reg прописывал, нажимал на кнопку что бы выдал список пользователей, но выдавал ошибку

Хм, а точно выполняется именно эта копия кода, может вы какую-то предыдущую версию кода запускаете? Проверьте. И приложите прмо в вопросе полный стек-трейс ошибки (все строки вывода об ошибке).

Все таки помогло убрать его из функций, спасибо!
